# Как добавить строку к строке в файле?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Появилась необходимость дописать определённый текст к строке в файле. Порядковый номер строки известен.

Было: `line |`
Добавляем: `_word |`
Стало: `line_word`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import fileinput as fi

line_no = N
word_to_add = "_word"

for line in fi.input("test.txt", inplace=True):
    new_line = f"{line.rstrip()}{word_to_add if fi.filelineno() == line_no else ''}\n"
    print(new_line, end="")
```